# Update a mysqli script into PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a rookie and I'm taking the first steps in the world of PDO and I'm trying to update this script from mysqli to PDO. The script is used to delete records from the database via jQuery.

The new connection to the mySql DB:

```
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root";
$password = ""; 
$dbname = "test-2"; 

try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}", $user, $password);
}

// show error
catch(PDOException $exception){
    echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

The problem concerns the DELETE script. This is the original (taken from this tutorial: https://makitweb.com/how-to-delete-record-from-mysql-table-with-ajax) with references to the old connection.

```
include "config.php";

$id = $_POST['id'];

if($id > 0){

  // Check record exists
  $checkRecord = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id_gallery=".$id);
  $totalrows = mysqli_num_rows($checkRecord);

  if($totalrows > 0){
    // Delete record
    $query = "DELETE FROM gallery WHERE id_gallery=".$id;
    mysqli_query($con,$query);
    echo 1;
    exit;
  }
}

echo 0;
exit;
```

and the same script I'm trying to update. It doesn't work because it gives me the '**invalid ID**' alert.

```
include "config.php";

$id = $_POST['id'];

if($id > 0){

  // Check record exists
  $checkRecord = "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id_gallery=".$id;
  $stmt = $con->prepare($checkRecord);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
     $stmt->execute();

  $totalrows = $stmt->fetchColumn()

  if($totalrows > 0){
    // Delete record
    $query = "DELETE FROM gallery WHERE id_gallery=".$id;
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 1;
    exit;
  }
}

echo 0;
exit;
```

script.js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.delete').click(function(){
        var el = this;
        var id = this.id;
        var splitid = id.split("_");

        // Delete id
        var deleteid = splitid[1];

        // AJAX Request
        $.ajax({
            url: 'remove.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id:deleteid },
            success: function(response){

                if(response == 1){
                    // Remove row from HTML Table
                    $(el).closest('tr').css('background','tomato');
                    $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800,function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                }else{
                    alert('Invalid ID.');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `$checkRecord = "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id_gallery=".$id;` this is still susceptible to SQLInjection.  If your going to use PDO, please don't concatenate any variables into the SQL  in this case it's possible the `$_POST['id']` is `foo` which because of the lack of quotes and prepared statement would result in this syntax error: `SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id_gallery=foo` ~ no quotes.To be clear putting `'` in there is not a way to solve this.  Also this may or may not be what is happening, but it's a possibility.  At the very least you should use `$id = (int)$_POST['id'];` or `intval()`

Comment: Check network tab and look if your ajax is calling and passing a correct id or not. If it is passing correct ID then check if your control appearing in if condition or not. You can do this file die or exit in each line of PHP code to debug your code.

Comment: I should mention posting the code in a well formatted, organized and minimal way is much appreciated.  So thank you for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither your original mysqli code nor your PDO code is actually creating any bound parameters.

You have this:

```
$checkRecord = "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id_gallery=".$id;
$stmt = $con->prepare($checkRecord);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

No doubt PDO is becoming confused when you requested to bindParam(), since you didn't put any parameter placeholders into the SQL query.  "Bind parameter... to what??" it rightly wonders.

You should use this:

```
$checkRecord = "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id_gallery=?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($checkRecord);
$stmt->execute([$id]);
```

More code examples are found in the documentation for [PDO::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Answer (score 0):

First question, do I really need to run this select? I suggest the code below

```
    include "config.php";

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    if($id > 0){

      // Delete record
      $checkRecord = "DELETE FROM gallery WHERE id_gallery= :id ";
      $stmt = $con->prepare($checkRecord);
      $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);      

      // It executes the delete, if any record is deleted, it will print "Registration deleted"
      if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "Registration deleted";
      }else{
        echo "Id does not exist";
      }
    }
exit;
```

I also suggest to always use the `PDO::PARAM_...`, as it will bring more security to your application

> – PDO::PARAM_STR – para valores strings, datas, horas…
>
> – PDO::PARAM_INT – para valores inteiros
>
> – PDO::PARAM_BOOL – para valor booleano (true ou false)
>
> – PDO::PARAM_NULL – valor nulo (null)
>
> – PDO::PARAM_LOB – representa valores de grande quantidade de dados
>
> – PDO::PARAM_STMT – representa um conjunto de registros, atualmente
>   não é suportado por nenhum driver
>
> – PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT – especifica que é um parâmetro de entrada e
>   saída para “stored procedures”

Comment: FYI, the MySQL PDO driver ignores the PDO::PARAM types. All types are passed to the server as if they are strings. Perhaps the types are more important in PDO drivers for other brands of SQL database.